# ODBC connection to postgresql database in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I use ODBC to connect my Power Bi desktop to a postgres database. My problem is that I can't refresh data from some tables (not all tables). I have this error :

```
 DataSource.Error:ODBC:ERROR[HY000]Error while executing the query
```

This problem appears recently (since I install Power Bi in another PC).

Do someone have any idea to fix this issue ? thanks.

Comment: Is the connection timing out? Are all of the tables accessible from the ODBC connection? Does the other PC have the tables locked?

Comment: the other PC had no problem. The connection isn't timing out, and all of the tables are accessible, the problem is that I can't load data from some tables